# Rails model where clause for has_many_through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have the following model setup:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :participents, through: :assignments
end
```

```
class Participent < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end
```

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end
```

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    # belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :participent
end
```

In my ParticipentsController I want to find projects that I did not participate to. But my code always returns all projects:

```
me = current_participent #current logged in user
Project.joins(:participents).where.not(participents: {id: me.id})
```

Can anyone point me to my mistake?

EDIT: me.id is not nil, it's a number object.
I also can reproduce this in rails console. For more context I post my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_09_03_173831) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.integer "participent_id"
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_client_id"
    t.index ["participent_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_participent_id"
  end

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_clients_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_clients_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "participents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_participents_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_participents_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_projects_on_client_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "projects", "clients"
end
```

**SOLUTION**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001556/890270

Comment: Can you check what me.id is? If it is nil, it will return all objects.

Comment: Can you provide attributes/column_name of Project and Participant table

Comment: me.id is 2
I added my schema.rb to the question

Comment: It's weird, Can u check `me.projects`?

Comment: This throws an error: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "project" or :projects in model Assignment. Try 'has_many :projects, :through => :assignments, :source => <name>'. Is it one of participent?)