# Alternative for Model.all - Model.where(condition)

Tags: model, where-clause, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-6

My question is quiet  simple: How to optimize the following query to not get performance issues once the database is growing:

```
def projects_not_participating
  @project = Project.all - Project.joins(:participants).where(participant: {id: current_user.id})
end
```

My model setup is this:

```
def Project
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :participants, through: :assignments
end
```

```
def Participant
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: assignments
end
```

I tried using

```
Project.joins(:participant).where.not(participant: {id: current_user.id})
```

but that returned all projects. I found out that the query is returning all table entries in `assignments` where `participant_id` is not the `current_user.id` and not grouping the project entries befor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I added a method to my `Project` class:

```
def self.not_participating(user)
  where.not(id: user.projects)
end
```

and use this in my `User` controller:

```
def find_projects
  @projects = Project.not_participating(current_user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're very close to a solution. The current problem is duplicating projects. To avoid this, you can use `distinct`:

```
Project.joins(:participants).where.not(participants: {id: current_user.id}).distinct
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't change the result. I think I need a distinct on `participant` but have no idea how to do this

Comment: I already used pluralized symbols for participants. It's not throwing an error, the result set is just wrong. here is the query rails is building with your code
`SELECT DISTINCT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "assignments"."project_id" = "projects"."id" INNER JOIN "participants" ON "participants"."id" = "assignments"."participant_id" WHERE "participants"."id" != ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]`

Comment: The problem with the query is that `participant_id` actually IS unequal to the `current_user.id` but there is another record for the same project but another participant and therefor the projects is included in the result set.